# Links inside Excel files should open Excel files in another library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, excel-services

We have a bunch of excel files that contains so many relative URLs to other documents. Now we are uploading source file to one location (Document Library) in SharePoint and uploading the linked file (destination) into other location (Document Library) in SharePoint. Is that possible now that the URL from the source file opens the linked file from the destination? If that's really possible, what would be the right solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

No. These links are relative links.

If your relative link is "`excels\destionation.xlsx`" in "`source.xlsx`" file. You upload the "`source.xlsx`" file to a document library named "doc". When you open "`source.xlsx`" from the library and check the link, this link will point to "`http://<current site>/doc/excels/destionation.xlsx`".

You need to modify the links manually if you upload source files and destination files to different libraries.